# Parsing and saving a nested JSON into SQLite, and then retrieving it

Tags: android, json, sqlite, gson

**Edit**

I managed to insert only the outer JSON object. Couldn't find information on how to insert nested objects. Each object has primitive fields in it. These objects can be seen in the JSON sample below: "languages" and "currencies". I also wonder how to deal with the "latlng" array within the outer JSON object, but it's probably better to handle these issues one at a time.

The code I got for inserting a primitive value in the outer JSON object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType();
List<Country> countriesList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);

for(Country country : countriesList) {
      ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
      insertValues.put(Country.NAME, country.getName());
      //more insertions
}
```

**The original question**

I parsed a nested JSON with GSON (probably incorrectly since it's my first time). Now I'm trying to insert it to SQLite. Couldn't find what needs to be written next. When I write the for loop for the insertion I get the error `cannot find symbol class Country`. Couldn't find relevant guidance online so I hope anyone can help in how to move forward.

That's where the issue begins:

```
Country[] countriesArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Country[].class);
for (int i = 0; i < countriesArray.length(); i++) {
...
            }
```

`countriesArray.length()` is marked as an error: cannot find symbol class Country.

**One object from the JSON:**

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":"Afghanistan",
      "topLevelDomain":[ 
         ".af"
      ],
      "callingCodes":[ 
         "93"
      ],
      "capital":"Kabul",
      "region":"Asia",
      "subregion":"Southern Asia",
      "population":27657145,
      "latlng":[ 
         33.0,
         65.0
      ],
      "demonym":"Afghan",
      "area":652230.0,
      "gini":27.8,
      "timezones":[ 
         "UTC+04:30"
      ],
      "nativeName":"افغانستان",
      "numericCode":"004",
      "currencies":[ 
         { 
            "name":"Afghan afghani",
            "symbol":"؋"
         }
      ],
      "languages":[ 
         { 
            "name":"Pashto",
            "nativeName":"پښتو"
         },
         { 
            "name":"Uzbek",
            "nativeName":"Oʻzbek"
         },
         { 
            "name":"Turkmen",
            "nativeName":"Türkmen"
         }
      ],
      "translations":{ 
         "de":"Afghanistan",
      },
      "flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
      "cioc":"AFG"
   },
```

The model classes I wrote are only for the variables objects and arrays I needed.

**The model class Country.Java**

```
public class Country implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String capital;
    private String region;
    private String subregion;
    private int population;
    private List<Double> latlng = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private double area;
    private double gini;
    private List<String> timezones = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Currency> currencies = new ArrayList<Currency>();
    private List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
    private String flag;

    public Country() {}

//getters, setters, toString() and Parcelable methods
}
```

**The model class Currency.Java**

```
public class Currency implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String symbol;

//getters, setters, toString() and Parcelable methods
}
```

**The model class Language.Java**

```
public class Language implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String nativeName;

//getters, setters, toString() and Parcelable methods
}
```

Comment: Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType();List<Country> countryList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);   Try this

Comment: Instead of "Type" I need to write County? What instead of "
Token"?

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a typeToken and pass it to fromJson method like following

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType();
List<Country> countryList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);
```

Comment: Thanks. The insertion to SQLite is done the same as without Gson? For instance: `String name = countyList.getString("name");`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson `TypeToken` to set the return object type during `JSON` parse

```
List<Country> countries  = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType());

for(Country country : countries) {
    //Do your DB operation here
}
```

Comment: @Joe, is my solution wrong? I gave you the solution first and someone repeated the same solution. It's ridicules.